# iOS - Merging two images of different size

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, merge, uiimage

I'm facing the following problem : I have to merge two images A and B to create a new image C as a result of the merging.
I already know how to merge two images but in this case my goal is a little bit different.
I would like that image A will be the background for Image B.
For instance if image A size is 500x500 and image B size is 460x460 I would like that image C (the  image result of the merging) will be 500x500, with image B (460x460) centered in it.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion

Comment: how are you merging - some code?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This is what I've done in my app, but without using `UIImageView`:

```
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom.png"]; //background image
UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"]; //foreground image

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

// Apply supplied opacity if applicable
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If the image already has opacity, you do not need to set it (as in bottomImage) otherwise you can set it (as with image).

After this `UIImage` is created then you can embed it in your `UIImageView`

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Ahmet AkkoK - for Swift (2.2) users blend mode macro has changed. `CGBlendMode .kCGBlendModeNormal` is replaced with `CGBlendMode.Normal`

Comment: @elio.d do you mind posting your completed solution here?  I am curious to see what you did and think it could be very helpful - thanks!

Comment: To @SrikarAppal, using your method the image resolution is dropped, like non-retina one. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I've found a way to solve the resolution problem: should double the value of width and height in UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and drawInRect.

Comment: @congliu yes since the resolution in retina is greater than normal. changing the dimensions in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is the way to go.

Comment: @SrikarAppal i am moving,zooming and rotating bottomImage so please tell me how can i set x,y coordinates and height,width ?

Comment: CGBlendMode.kCGBlendModeNormal is replaced with CGBlendMode.Normal in the Swift version I'm using (Swift 2.2).

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya have you find any solution for zoomed and rotated image?

Comment: @PramodTapaniya yes

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya please write answer .

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya in this que http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119172/merging-two-images-of-different-size-with-rotate-and-zoom

Answer (score 13):

Hey i got multiple images add same background with different foreground
This is my code

```
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 2.JPG"]; //background image
UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 3.JPG"]; //foreground image
UIImage *image1      = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 4.JPG"]; //foreground image
UIImage *image2      = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 5.JPG"]; //foreground image

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

// Apply supplied opacity if applicable
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.4];
[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.3];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.2];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

resultView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
resultView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,320,460);
[self.view addSubview:resultView];
```

Answer (score 7):

### Swift version

*Copy/Paste to Playground*

```
var bottomImage:UIImage = UIImage(named:"avatar_4.png") //background image
```

[image]

```
var imageTop:UIImage  = UIImage(named:"group_4.png")    //top image
```

[image]

```
var newSize = CGSizeMake(bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize )
    
bottomImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height))

// decrease top image to 36x36 
imageTop.drawInRect(CGRectMake(18,18,36,36), blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha:1.0)

var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)
```

[image]

---

To load images from playground:

- Open `playground` file and create there folder `Resources`
- copy images to this folder

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just made quick paste function for those of you who wanted to use [Srikar Appal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147019/srikar-appal) answer. (if in case background & foreground images are of different sizes)

```
- (UIImage *) mergeImages:(NSString *)bgImageFileName foreGround:(NSString *)fgImageFileName  {
    UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:bgImageFileName]; //background image
    UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageNamed:fgImageFileName]; //foreground image

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    // Change xPos, yPos if applicable
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(11,11,image.size.width,image.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: i am moving,zooming and rotating foreground image so please tell me how can i set x,y coordinates and height,width ?

Answer (score 2):

in Swift:

```
let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "Bottom_Image.png")
    let frontImage = UIImage (named: "Front_Image.png")
    let size = CGSize(width: 67, height: 55)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    let frontImageSize = CGRect(x: 14, y: 3, width: 40, height: 40)
    bottomImage!.drawInRect(areaSize, blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha:  1.0)
    frontImage!.drawInRect(frontImageSize, blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha: 1.0)

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Srikar Appal for iOS soultion.

For anyone who is looking for merge in OS X:

```
- (NSImage *) mergeImages:(NSString *)bgImageFileName foreGround:(NSString *)fgImageFileName {
    NSImage *bottomImage = [NSImage imageNamed:bgImageFileName];
    NSImage *overlayedImage = [NSImage imageNamed:fgImageFileName];

    NSSize newSize = NSMakeSize(bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height);
    NSSize overlaySize = NSMakeSize(newSize.width/2, newSize.height/2); //change the size according to your requirements

    NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:newSize];

    [newImage lockFocus];

    [bottomImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    [overlayedImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(newSize.width-overlaySize.width, 0, overlaySize.width, overlaySize.height)]; //set the position as required

    [newImage unlockFocus];

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell whats wrong with the solution, why it was down voted ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with **another trick** as described below:

1. Add first image to a imageView.
2. Add second image to another imageView.
3. Add both the above imageViews in a single main imageView and access the combined image by property of imageView : **mainImageView.image**

Have a look at the code below :

```
    CGRect rect= investmentDetailTblView.frame;
    int rows = investmentDetailArray.count;

    CGFloat heightFinal = 5;
    CGRect frame1;

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
         frame1 = [investmentDetailTblView rectForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        CGFloat height = frame1.size.height;

        heightFinal = heightFinal + height;
    }
    rect.size.height = heightFinal;

    investmentDetailTblView.frame=rect;

    UIImageView *imageViewTable = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [imageViewTable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame1.size.width, heightFinal)];


    [investmentDetailTblView reloadData];

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(investmentDetailTblView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(investmentDetailTblView.bounds.size);

    [investmentDetailTblView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imageViewTable.image = image; //Adding the table image to the image view.


    CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, heightFinal+5, investmentDetailTblView.frame.size.width, 20) ;
    UIView *footerView=[DataStore kkrLogoView];

    footerView.frame=frame;

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(footerView.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(footerView.frame.size);

    [footerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *kkrLogoImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *imageViewFooter = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imageViewFooter setFrame:CGRectMake(0, heightFinal, footerView.frame.size.width, footerView.frame.size.height)];
    imageViewFooter.image = kkrLogoImage; //Adding the footer image to the image view.


    UIImageView *mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [mainImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame1.size.width, (heightFinal+footerView.frame.size.height))];

    [mainImageView addSubview:imageViewTable];
    [mainImageView addSubview:imageViewFooter];

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImageView.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size);

    [mainImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```