# is there any way to take a screenshot when MPMoviePlayerController is playing

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, screenshot, capture

I tried below steps to capture screenshot but got black backround for MPMoviePlayerController

```
-(UIImage*)screenshot
{
 CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

CGFloat imageScale = imageSize.width / FRAME_WIDTH;

if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, imageScale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

get `image` from `MPMoviePlayerController` like this on `action` of `button`:

```
-(void)getScreenShotOfMPMoviePlayerController:(MPMoviePlayerController *)mpPlayer
{
   UIImage *thumbnail = [mpPlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:yourMoviePlayerObject.currentPlaybackTime 
                       timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
}
```

**EDIT** : `Merge` both `images` as one image taken from `MPMoviePlayerController` with the `ScreenShot` taken from `UIWindow`.

Refer [ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208951/ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size) link for merging.

Comment: But, it will give only thumbnail of MPMoviePlayerController. I have other elements also on the screen with MPMoviePlayerController, and I want to capture all of them at a time.

Comment: this method is deprecated now, what to use instead?

Comment: @Stas I believe the correct method to use now is `requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes`.