# Not able to merge two images into one

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, image

I'm trying to merge two images in one, and save that image onto the camera roll. But it just show a blank image. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
-(void)SaveFinalImage{    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *savedImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(savedImg, nil, nil, nil);     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this in my app.

```
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom.png"]; //background image
UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"]; //foreground image

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

// Apply supplied opacity if applicable
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

for more see my related answer on the same subject. [iOS - Merging two images of different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208951/ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size/9209044#9209044)