# How to combine two UIImages of difference size without altering their original aspect ratios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

My current method of combining UIImages come from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208951/ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size) on SO, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio) popular question on resizing UIImage with aspect ratio.  My current issue is the following:

I have an UIImage called `pictureImage` taken with the camera that comes out to the standard dimension `2448*3264`. I also have a UIImageView called `self.annotateView` that has a frame of `320*568` where the user could draw and annotate the picture. When I present the `pictureImage` in a `UIImageView`, I set the image presentation as **Aspect Fill** so that it takes up the whole iPhone screen. Of course this means parts of `pictureImage` is cut off on both left and right (in fact 304 pixels on both sides), but this intended.

My problem is, when I combine the UIImages `pictureImage` and `annotateView.image` to a new dimension of `320*568`, my combined image alters the original aspects of `annotateView.image` by stretching it horizontally. This is strange since the new dimensions are exactly that of `annotateView.image`'s original dimensions.

Here is what the outcome looks like -

Before combining the UIImages

[image]

After combining the images

[image]

Note that the underlying picture is not stretched.  However, `annotateView.image` is stretched only horizontally, not vertically.

Here is my code for merging the UIImages.

```
//Note: self.firstTakenImage is set to 320*568

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.firstTakenImage.frame.size.width, self.firstTakenImage.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[self.firstTakenImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
[self.drawView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: is firstTakenImage is the snapshot captured from cam? which initailly has 2048*3264.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While doing the drawInRect, you have to redo the scaling and centering that the system did for you with AspectFill to make it match the original process. Something like this:

```
CGSize fullSize = self.pictureView.image.size;
CGSize newSize = self.outputView.frame.size;
CGFloat scale = newSize.height/fullSize.height;
CGFloat offset = (newSize.width - fullSize.width*scale)/2;
CGRect offsetRect = CGRectMake(offset, 0, newSize.width-offset*2, newSize.height);
NSLog(@"offset = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(offsetRect));

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[self.pictureView.image drawInRect:offsetRect];
[self.annotateView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage *combImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.outputView.image = combImage;
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this answer. Unfortunately, the outcome from the code is that `pictureImage` is now proportionally stretched to match that of `annotateView.image`, rather than the intended opposite of `annotateView.image` being shrinked proportionally to match `pictureImage`.  Will tweak this code a bit to see whether I could come up with a solution.

Comment: Hmm, a couple of diagnostic questions: are you setting the view.contentMode for the outputView? Are you sure that newSize is being set correctly?

Comment: You're right! I was making some additional modifications to `combImage` later on in a different controller, and hence the stretched outness.  Thanks - this solution worked :)

Answer (score 2):

- Support Portrait and Landscape both type of image
- Drawing and other subviews can be merged in my case I'm adding label to draw

```html
  {

    CGSize fullSize = getImageForEdit.size;
    CGSize sizeInView = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imgViewFake.image.size, imgViewFake.bounds).size;
    CGFloat orgScale = orgScale = fullSize.width/sizeInView.width;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(orgScale * img.image.size.width, orgScale * img.image.size.height);
    if(newSize.width <= fullSize.width && newSize.height <= fullSize.height){
        newSize = fullSize;
    }
    CGRect offsetRect;
    if (getImageForEdit.size.height > getImageForEdit.size.width){
        CGFloat scale = newSize.height/fullSize.height;
        CGFloat offset = (newSize.width - fullSize.width*scale)/2;
        offsetRect = CGRectMake(offset, 0, newSize.width-offset*2, newSize.height);
    }
    else{
        CGFloat scale = newSize.width/fullSize.width;
        CGFloat offset = (newSize.height - fullSize.height*scale)/2;
        offsetRect = CGRectMake(0, offset, newSize.width, newSize.height-offset*2);
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, getImageForEdit.scale);
    [getImageForEdit drawAtPoint:offsetRect.origin];
    //        [img.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    CGFloat oldScale = img.contentScaleFactor;
    img.contentScaleFactor = getImageForEdit.scale;
    [img drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    img.contentScaleFactor = oldScale;
    UIImage *combImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(combImage, 1);
}
```

Comment: For quality of image you can replace 'UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);'   with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, getImageForEdit.scale);

Answer (score 1):

When you call `[self.drawView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];` you need to modify the frame to account for the difference in aspect ratio that you described (because you are chopping some of the image off on both sides).

That means modifying the `x` position and the `width` that you are drawing the annotation image.

The modification is based on the difference between the 2 rects when scaled to the same height. You say this is `304`, so you can initially set `x` to 304 and the `width` to `newSize.width - 608` to test. But really the difference should be calculated...

Answer (score 0):

**Mackworth's answer in Swift 3.x**

```
    let fullSize:CGSize = img.size
    let newSize:CGSize = fullSize
    let scale:CGFloat = newSize.height/fullSize.height
    let offset:CGFloat = (newSize.width - fullSize.width*scale)/2
    let offsetRect:CGRect = CGRect.init(x: offset, y: 0, width: newSize.width - offset*2, height: newSize.height)
    print(NSStringFromCGRect(offsetRect))     

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    self.pictureView.image.draw(in: offsetRect)
    self.annotateView.image.draw(in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: waterMarkImage.size.width, height: waterMarkImage.size.height))
    let combImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return combImage;
```

Comment: What about if we need to merge image with a view ? :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931810/capture-screen-based-on-uiimage-size?noredirect=1#comment76840416_44931810