# How to add multiple images to image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

i have a view i added text and images on that view. i want that if i added one image then at the same time i also added next and next image, but i have problem in that. when i move one image in that specific view then the other images also there not to be disappeared.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    self.imageView.hidden =NO;

    self.imageView .image = image;

    [txtNotes addSubview:self.imageView];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

[image]

Comment: check my answer. i think you have any array of images.. then write below code.

Comment: you have not replied.

Comment: wait i am checking  @Asoke Londhe

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an image view for image dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163228/how-to-create-an-image-view-for-image-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to show images on imagesView....

```
UIImageView *imageView;
NSArray *arrayOfImage=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"i1.jpg",@"i2.jpg",@"i3.png", nil];;
float x=10;
float y=50;
float width=100;
float height=100;
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<[arrayOfImage count];i++)
{
   imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+width*i, y, width, height)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfImage objectAtIndex:i]]];
     [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
else if(i==[arrayOfImage count])
    {
        i=0;
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfImage objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        i++;

    }
```

if you want to change the I'm image on next button and back button... then try below code

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{

UIImageView *imageView;
NSArray *arrayOfImage=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"i1.jpg",@"i2.jpg",@"i3.png",@"i1.jpg",@"i2.jpg",@"i3.png", nil];;
float x=100;
float y=100;
float width=100;
float height=100;

imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
if([sender tag]==0)
{
    if(i<[arrayOfImage count])
    {
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfImage objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        i++;
    }
    else if(i==[arrayOfImage count])
    {
        i=0;
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfImage objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        i++;

    }

}else
{
    if(i<[arrayOfImage count])
    {
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfImage objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        i--;
    }
    else if(i==-1)
    {
        i=0;
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfImage objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        i++;

    }

}


}
```

Note: set Tag to Next button as 0 and set tag to back button as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple UIImageViews and before placing them using addSubview, set them a frame, which will be different for every UIImageView.

Putting multiple images into one UIImageView is certainly possible, but achievable probably only by merging images into one, which I would not consider the best option. How to do that, you can find in accepted answer there:

[iOS - Merging two images of different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208951/ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size)