# Customize marker on Google Map

Tags: ios, iphone

In my ios application I want to use custom Marker which has profile picture of user in oval shape.So I'm not getting how to do this...

[image]

```
  {    _markerFinish.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redMap.png"];
         _markerFinish.map = gmsMapView;
         _markerFinish.position = endPoint;   
  }
```

Comment: show your tried code and what the problem u faced

Comment: my problem is with i'm not able to show userprofile pic,Fine with background redImage

Comment: how to add profile pic on marker in oval shape

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face this:

This will work for me.

Try this:[iOS - Merging two images of different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208951/ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size)

Happy coding :)