# How as one ImageView show pictures of different size properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a controller in which there are various questions and images.

In each question all the elements (images, button) are shifted relative to the size of the text. But I also have pictures of different sizes. How as one `ImageView` show pictures of different size correctly, so that they adjust to the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want image to show on full size of imageView you should use this:

this will scale image on Aspect Fill

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

also there are few more Keywords: `AspectFit`, `ScaleToFill`

> swift 2.0 version:

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

also you can add `autoresizingMask`:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask =   
    ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth );
```

Comment: No, the pictures have a different aspect ratio . I need to transfer ratio by different images in one imageView.

Comment: you need multiple images in one imageView with different sources?

Comment: Yes. which have different aspect ratio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208951/ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size follow this link

Comment: In this case, the coordinates have to be set manually.
I use auto layout and which is placed the image depends on the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, change `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` to fill in encapsulated image:

```
myImageView.image = myImage;
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

**Second**, adjust image view frame per current image

```
CGRect frame = myImageView.frame;
frame.size = myImage.size;
myImageView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: I use auto layout and which is placed the image depends on the size of the text.